# How can I troubleshoot high latency issues with StarCraft:BW?

Tags: networking, starcraft

A couple of friends and myself have been trying to play StarCraft: Brood War on Battle.net, but every time we try to join each others' game we always get a 'High Latency Issue' and full red bars next to the game name.

We've searched for answers, and tried opening our ports like Battle.net recommends but so far nothing has worked.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: to be clear, you don't experience high latency when playing on Battle.Net with other people?

Comment: When my friends, or myself try to join each-others games we get the 'High Latency Issue"

Comment: it should be one of you that is dragging everyone else. You should try to isolate the bad connection by connecting in pairs only, and see who experiences latency and who doesn't.

Comment: Are some of you sharing a connection, router, etc. ?

Comment: No, we are all in separate homes, using different routers and internet connections.

Answer (score 2):

Try having a third party host a game for you. Alternatively, you can try joining your friend's game and then leaving and hosting a game afterward. Somehow this can "clear" you to join without latency issues thereafter.

Both techniques have solved similar issues for me in the past.

Comment: If it is a connectivity problem, choosing a different host will not fix the problem.  RTS's do not use client-server architecture like most FPS's - everyone is as slow as the slowest player.  Likely, one of the players has a very bad network connection.  See [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15192/2061) for more info on how most networked RTS's work.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the logic behind this, but I have played SC:BW for 12 years and this has fixed the problem for many people in the past, including me. Two players can have excellent connections and not cause any lag at all except when they play in the same game. Again- I don't know why it works, just that it does. Please don't vote down solutions on intuition without having tried them.

Comment: Neat trick. The both trying to host a game sounds like a UDP hole punching technique. Routers often let through packets from some IP after you've sent some to that IP. The earlier join attempt sends such packets.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a router, try to open 6112-6117 UDP ports.

And also to make better latency of while playing games.

Try to use Chaoslauncher and make rooms with #L2, #L1 at the end.

Although you will be able to play with players with launcher with that title name.

You can feel like you're playing in UDP or IPX but not in Battle.net

Comment: "Latency too high" is the error you get when a connection attempt to the host times out. So port forwarding is relevant, but Chaoslaucher/LatencyChanger are irrelevant for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a connectivity problem than a gaming problem. Each individual should run some tests to determine their latency to given servers.

First, run a continuous ping from your computer to your ISPs primary DNS for about an hour (in windows, use ping -t ). When complete, check the minimum, maximum and average. All of these should be about the same and should be no more than about 100 ms. Battle.net does not have ICMP enabled, so you can't ping each individual server directly, but you can run a traceroute (tracert uswest.battle.net) to see each individual hop along the way and see how you are routed to that particular server. You can alternatively use pathping to get more detailed results about latency to each hop along the way.

Once everyone has run these tests you should be able to compare results and see which of your connections is providing the high ping times. If those pings times are on the network side of their ISP, they might be able to get their ISP to fix the issue. If the high ping times are the result of a bad route or server elsewhere on that route, they may be able to appeal to their ISP for a re-route, but don't hold your breath on this option.

Comment: Both ping and connection are irrelevant to this problem. This is a router issue.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, How is it a router issue if it is 3 separate connections? Also, ping = latency, so how is ping irrelevant?

Comment: The first issue is that the error really means "Connection timeout". It's just badly formulated. The user who joins the game sends a UDP packet to the host and if he doesn't get a response within a few seconds you get this message. In almost all cases this is due to the host not forwarding the correct port (UDP 6112 or sometimes 6113-6118). In some rare cases it's due to the client not receiving the response. The connection to battle.net itself doesn't matter for this at all. The game itself is purely peer-to-peer between the players.